# $F$ fixed ultra filter $\Rightarrow$ $F=F_{\{x\}} = \{U \subset X | \{x\} \subset U \}$

Tags: general-topology

$F$ fixed ultra filter $\Rightarrow$ $F=F_{\{x\}} = \{U \subset X \mid \{x\} \subset U \}$

This is what I have come up with

Assume $F \not = F_{\{x\}} \Rightarrow \exists U \in F : \{x\} \not \in F$. Since $F$ is fixed $\exists y \in \cap_{f \in F} \ f : y \not = x$. I would like to claim that this contradicts the assumption that $F$ is ultra filter, can I do that?

A fixed filter is one that is not free, and a filter $F$ is free if $\cap_{f \in F} f = \emptyset$

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but it seems you are claiming that any ultrafilter is a *principal* ultrafilter. This is not generally true.

Comment: No, any **fixed** ultra filer. @hardmath

Comment: ???? *By definition* a fixed (ultra)filter has the form $F_{\{x\}} = \{U \subset X \mid \{x\} \subset U \}$ Are you trying to prove that a fixed filter is an ultrafilter?

Comment: We defined a fixed filter to be a filter that is not free, and an ultra filter is a filter that is maximal. @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla

Comment: The only use of "fixed" ultrafilter I've seen makes it a synonym of principal ultrafilter.  See this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter).   Given that your definition is different (I don't know what makes a filter "not free"), you should give the details in the body of your Question.

Comment: See my edit. @hardmath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fixed ultrafilter has $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \neq \emptyset$. Let $a$ be a point in it.

Then $\mathcal{F} \cup \{a\}$ is a filter base (as it has the finite intersection property, because $a \in F$ for all members of $\mathcal{F}$).
So this generates a filter $\mathcal{F}'$ which then contains $\mathcal{F}$ so must equal $\mathcal{F}$ by maximality of $\mathcal{F}$.

So $\{a\} \in \mathcal{F}$. But then the enlargement axiom
tells us that $F_a \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. The reverse is true as all members of $\mathcal{F}$ contain $a$.

Comment: Enlargement axiom?

Comment: @Olba12 if a filter contains a set, it also contains all larger sets (supersets). There is also the finite intersection axiom, and not having $\emptyset$ in it, or equivalently $\mathcal{F} \neq \mathcal{P}(X)$. (being proper).

Comment: Ah yes, was not familiar with the name though.